# Angular 4 shared component creating new instances on every load

Tags: angular

I am using [Core UI](http://coreui.io) as the dashboard template but with a few modifications. The template is divided in modules but, the `sidebar` menu is enough to make it work. Because my app is a bit bigger I'm using the top menu for navigation and the `sidebar` menu changes depending on the module. The problem I'm having is that the breadcrumb component is instantiated every time you switch modules and in the end you can end up with +50 instances if not more.

The App module looks like this:

```
// App component
@Component({
    selector: 'body',
    template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`
})
export class AppComponent {
}

// App routing
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot([
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'Dashboard',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: '',
        component: LayoutComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'Dashboard',
                loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
            }
        ]
    }
])],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}

// App module
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        CoreModule,
        SharedModule,
        AppRoutingModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        LAYOUT_DECLARATIONS
    ],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: LocationStrategy,
            useClass: HashLocationStrategy
        }
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}

// Layout component template
<header class="app-header navbar">
    <button appMobileSidebarToggler class="d-lg-none navbar-toggler" type="button">&#9776;</button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
    <ul class="d-md-down-none nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a appSidebarToggler class="navbar-toggler nav-link" href="#">&#9776;</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <a class="nav-link" i18n routerLink="/Dashboard" routerLinkActive="active">Dashboard</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</header>
<div class="app-body">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

The Dashboard code:

```
// Dashboard component
@Component({
    selector: 'app-dashboard',
    templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html'
})

export class DashboardComponent { 
}

// Dashboard routes
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: DashboadComponent,
        data: {
            title: 'Dashboad'
        },
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                component: DashboardHomeComponent,
                data: {
                    title: 'Home'
                }
            }
        ]
    }
];)
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class DashboardRoutingModule {
}

// Dashboard module
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        SharedModule,
        DashboardRoutingModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        DashboadComponent,
        DashboardHomeComponent
    ]
})
export class DashboadModule {
}

//Dashboard layout
<div class="sidebar">
    <nav class="sidebar-nav">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <!-- Module navigation -->
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
<main class="main">
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <app-breadcrumbs></app-breadcrumbs>
    </ol>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</main>
```

I omitted the imports because everything compiles OK. The top menu in the layout template will have 4 more links and each time the user switches modules a new instance of the `breadcrumb` component will be created because the breadcrumb component is in the `shared` module. Is there any way to transclude the `breadcrumb` component from the layout template to the dashboard template? Or any other solution to this problem?

Comment: I'm slightly confused. Are you saying that it behaves incorrectly or are you saying that it is simply an efficiency issue?

Comment: An efficiency issue. I'm new to Angular 4 but I think that it should be making a new instance every time a new feature module is loaded

Comment: Perhaps not, but I would not worry about it unless you notice a memory _leak_.

Comment: The breadcrumb component just goes trough the route children, and thats about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Breadcrumb component was in the child modules and it should have been in the parent module.